# Regex extraction of substrings ignoring internal character used to match

Tags: regex, string, keyvaluepair

I'm matching a string of a key value pair between characters "" with `"(.*?)"` how can I ignore any extra " characters within the value part.

example string `{"1"=>"email@example.com"}`

Comment: Could you please clarify *any extra " characters within the value part*? `"(.*?)"` finds all occurrences of substrings between double quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Example: {"1"=>"somest"ring" } For the value part I want to extract exactly as they entered it. result= somest"ring

Comment: It is wrong, it should be `"somes\"tring"`. Please have it fixed on the provider's side. All workarounds are not nice. You might try `String pat = "(?<=\\{|=>)\"(.*?)\"(?=\\}|=>)"` but it might still fail in edge cases. See https://regex101.com/r/rduF7v/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew agreed it's broken - this will see me through. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
String pat = "(?<=\\{|=>)\"(.*?)\"(?=\\}|=>)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rduF7v/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\{|=>)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `{` or `=>`
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `"` - a double quotation mark
- `(?=\}|=>)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location immediately followed with `}` or `=>`.